# Grid property instead of grid-row & grid-column

Tags: css, css-grid, grid-layout

According to [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid), the `grid` CSS property is a shorthand property that sets all of the explicit and implicit grid properties in a single declaration. I wonder how we can use it instead of `grid-row` & `grid-column` in the following sample code so it can be further shortened:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item3 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't the grid property used to define the properties of the grid whereas grid-row and grid-column tell the system where to put an element with those properties?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [`grid-area`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area). `grid` is for the container

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item3 {
  /*grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;*/
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 /auto; 
  /* row-start / column-start / row-end / column-end */
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not the purpose of it. The shorthand replaces `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows` on the grid container.

Answer (score 0):

The *grid* property is a shorthand for the following:

- grid-auto-columns
- grid-auto-flow
- grid-auto-rows
- grid-template-areas
- grid-template-columns
- grid-template-rows

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid
This property is used to define the grid itself, so it's something you would add to grid-container rather than to its children.

You could shorten your statement in item3 using grid-area, which is shorthand for:

- grid-row-start
- grid-column-start
- grid-row-end
- grid-column-end

  So item3 could be styled as:

  .item3 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3;
  }